# PyCharm shortcut to expand text editor component

Tags: pycharm, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

In PyCharm, when you double-click an opened file tab, IDE's other components (as *console* or *project tool window*, etc) are all minimized, giving the whole window focus to the *editor tab component*:

[image]

I was looking up at `settings > keymap` for a slot to add / edit this action's shortcut, however I couldn't identified it.

How could I configure a keyboard shortcut to this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `Hide All Windows` action.

Check `Window - Active Tool Window - Hide All Windows` for the shortcut.

Comment: Nice! it's exactly this... Thanks